# I think [override] [overrides] [method-overriding], [function-overriding], and even [overriding] itself

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I've recently edited a question which was incorrectly referring to overloading instead of overriding. When replacing the tag as well, I found I have a rather wide selection to choose from; too wide, in fact. There's:

- [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), with ~3.6k questions, and a two-paragraph wiki distinct from its excerpt.
- [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding), with ~600 questions, excerpt identical to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), and no wiki.
- [method-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-overriding), with ~280 questions, excerpt identical to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override), and no wiki.
- [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overrides), with ~90 questions, and a two-paragraph wiki where the first one is a copy of the excerpt.
- [function-overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-overriding), with ~70 questions, no excerpt, and no wiki.

This doesn't look coherent, or really usable, to me. In my view, the best solution would be to:

1. Introduce a synonym `overriding` -> `override`
2. Re-tag `method-overriding`, `function-overriding`, and `overrides` to `override`.

I prefer `override` as the master version because it a) has the largest number of questions, and b) matches the spelling of the related keyword in C++ and other languages.

At the same time, `overriding` seems used enough to warrant its existence as a synonym, and I've already suggested it as such.

Is this a sensible course of action?

Comment: It's difficult, but `override` indeed is what the tag is called in most languages. However, then one might say `overloading` should be changed to `overload`, which seems wrong. In that regard, I would prefer `overriding`.

Comment: I don't have enough [overriding] reputation to be eligible to vote for such a synonym. Maybe my software design skills are just too good, so I don't need inheritance.

Answer (score 25):

## We should synonymize them all to [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding).

There's no harm in all the other synonyms, they serve a useful purpose of helping people find the correct tag when asking a question, and it's less work than retagging.

Although, as you point out, `override` is an actual keyword in numerous languages, there are times when you want to ask about the usage of the keyword itself, rather than the concept which the keyword is primarily used to accomplish.  For example, in C++ the 'inline' keyword has some no-so-subtle differences from the compiler optimization of [inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inlining).  C++ also allows overriding a member function without using the `override` keyword, so there are likely to be some questions about the keyword specifically rather than the OOP concept.

Therefore, we should end up with two tags, [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding) and [override-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override-keyword).  Having the synonym [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override)->[overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding) is fine, because the existence of [override-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override-keyword) will be shown as a suggestion.

Bring the [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) wiki across to [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding), and write a new one for [override-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override-keyword) if it ever gets used.

Comment: Why not [tag:override] and [tag:override-keyword]?  [tag:override-keyword] is a relative corner case, and I don't think we should make the root synonym *worse* for a corner case if it isn't required.

Answer (score 24):

## Tl;dr: I agree with your analysis completely.

---

### Edit:

#### Concern:

My concern would be that the tags are used for questions specific to things different about method, function, etc.. overriding. But since the tags themselves don't have the excepts or wikis to back that up, I am inclined to say "Go for it".

#### The Solution:

Your solution is extremely efficient and preserves the existing infrastructure. Any questions regard specific method vs function overriding would be covered with regard to the language and framework anyways, so those tags would be involved and redundancy in the overriding tag is not required.

Comment: @rene: Actually, it is.  The post is tagged [tag:discussion] not [tag:feature-request], so upvotes on the question indicate that people found the discussion informative.  An answer is needed to collect votes agreeing or disagreeing with the proposed course of action.

Comment: I also fixed my answer to discuss what exactly i was agreeing with.